# How to vertically align the elements in two divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

```
<div id="div1">

    <label class="someClass1">Price 1</label>
    <label class="someClass1">Price 2</label> 
    <label class="someClass1">Price 3</label> 
    <label class="someClass1">Price 4</label> 
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <input type="text" class="someClass2"/>
    <input type="text" class="someClass2"/>
    <input type="text" class="someClass2"/>
    <input type="text" class="someClass2"/>
</div>
```

I have two divs. One div contains `<label>` elements and another div contains `<input>` elements. The two divs are aligned horizontally. I need to align the labels and input elements vertically so that each label has it's input underneath.

I may achieve the above requirement by putting the `<label>` and `<input>` elements by placing them in `<table>` rows/columns. But I require them to use `<div>`.

Could someone help me out on this ?

Comment: Will these two `div`s guaranteed to have the same width?

Comment: @Passerby : I've not defined the fixed width for the divs. Should I ??

Comment: Then is it OK to specify fixed width on both `label`s and `input`s, like Jan's answer?

Comment: yes, we can set the fixed width on both input and label elements.

Comment: Is this acceptable: http://jsfiddle.net/2wdUT/1/ ? (It's also in Jan's answer's comment)

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**, try this CSS

```
#div1 label.someClass1 { display: inline-block; margin: 0 5px; }
#div1 label.someClass1, #div2 input.someClass2 { width: 100px; }
#div2 input.someClass2 { margin: 0 0 0 10px; }
```

---

**Long answer**, to make the exact look you pictured in your question, use HTML5 placeholder attribute and CSS3 border-radius:

```
#div1 label {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
#div1 label, #div2 input {
  width: 100px;
}
#div2 input {
  border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px; 
}
```

.

```
<div id="div1">
    <label>Price 1</label>
    <label>Price 2</label> 
    <label>Price 3</label> 
    <label>Price 4</label> 
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Price"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Price"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Price"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Price"/>
</div>
```

To finetune CSS3 effects, see [css3generator](http://css3generator.com/)

Comment: The vertical alignment is still not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

To get the divs on same row with inputs below them, use below css

```
#div1 label { display: inline-block; }
#div1 label, #div2 input { width: 100px; }
```

Check Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/2wdUT/

Comment: The vertical alignment is still not perfect.

Comment: @JanTuroň I think this may have been a good-faith effort to provide a answer, improving on yours. That is a valid way to answer, usually. A comment on your answer would have been appropriate, too. See also my comment to harishannam below.

Comment: @harishannam Do be careful about copying from another person's answer. I understand you did a minor correction, and that's a valid reason to post your own answer. When you are doing so, with such minor adjustments, it's usually good to include a note that you are taking your base info from another user's post.

Answer (score 0):

Without css you can achieve it by using such an HTML structure -

```
    <div id="div1">
      <label class="someClass1">Price 1</label>
      <div><input type="text" class="someClass2"/></div>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
      <label class="someClass1">Price 2</label> 
      <div><input type="text" class="someClass2"/></div>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
      <label class="someClass1">Price 3</label>  
      <div><input type="text" class="someClass2"/></div>
    </div>
    <div id="div4">
      <label class="someClass1">Price 4</label> 
      <div><input type="text" class="someClass2"/></div>    
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't do that. I need to insert the labels and input elements dynamically. All I have beforehand is only the two divs aligned horizontally.

Comment: This is vertical arrangement and the OP wants horizontal arrangement.